# How to get image absolute path?

Tags: java, jsp

How to get image path in java ?

I am using eclipse, i want to display the image in jsp,I want to give path like "/images/logo.jpg" but it is getting nullpointer exception when execute the page.

if i give fullpath , it is working like "d:/project/images/logo.jsp".How to get display the image with absolute path ?

Comment: what if you use "images/logo.jpg" so the path is relative?

Comment: You mean a relative path? Try omitting the first slash and see if that works. (edit: Fosco: jinx!)

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid using relative paths in `java.io` stuff as much as possible. Any relative path will be relative to the current working directory which is dependent on the way how you started the application and is uncontrollable from inside the code. When started as e.g. a Tomcat service, it will be relative to `c:/path/to/tomcat/bin`. When running in Eclipse, it will be relative to `c:/path/to/eclipse/project/bin`. When running in command console, it will be relative to currently opened folder. Etcetera. You don't want to be dependent on that. Bad idea.

In case of JSP/Servlet webapplications there are basically two ways to obtain an absolute resource path using a relative path in a reliable way:

1. Retrieve it from the **runtime classpath** (there where all the classes and libraries are):

   ```
   ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
   String path = classLoader.getResource("/images/logo.jpg").getPath();
   ```
2. Retrieve it from the **webcontent** (there where all the JSP files and `/WEB-INF` folder are):

   ```
   ServletContext context = getServletContext(); // Inherited from HttpServlet.
   String path = context.getResource("/images/logo.jpg").getPath();
   ```

If all you ultimately want is an `InputStream` out of it, which you perhaps intented to create using `new FileInputStream(path)`, then you should be using `getResourceAsStream()` methods instead:

1. From classpath:

   ```
   InputStream content= classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/images/logo.jpg");
   ```
2. Or webcontent:

   ```
   InputStream content = context.getResourceAsStream("/images/logo.jpg");
   ```

Comment: At last! I've been looking for this answer for almost 4 hours..! Nobody talked about `ClassLoeader` or `ServletContext` at all. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `/images/logo.jpg` put `images/logo.jpg` i.e. remove the first slash.

Comment: Image image = Image.getInstance("images/logo.jpg");
This code inside pdf generation using itext.

Comment: Then you have to do something like 

URL imgURL = getClass().getResource("images/logo.jpg");
Image img = new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage();