# save jpeg format in ms access and show it on panel in swing

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans

I m working on a application which has a form with a space for photo. I want to fill this blank space with photo which is stored in the database (MS Access) but the problems are-

1) I dont know how to store photo in MS Access
2) I dont know which method uses to retrieve the photo from database.

I m using Netbeans IDE and Java for gui making.

Please help me to do this job

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you're going to use. We can use 2 approaches such as saving path address or save the image onto the Binary Data but based on my opinion I would like to save the data using path address so it can optimize performance.

Hope it helps you.

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/250763/image-to-ms-access

or

[How to get image absolute path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205503/how-to-get-image-absolute-path)